# I want to retrive the chat between two users , please guide me how could I code?

Tags: server, xmpp, openfire

`Is it possible to retrieve the chat between the two users?

I am giving my code please if anyone could help?
The below code is not working for me.

version used :
<java.version>17</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>

<smack.version>4.4.6</smack.version>

<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

```
public class ChatRetrieve {

    public static List<Message> retrieveChatMessages(AbstractXMPPConnection connection, EntityBareJid userJid) throws Exception {
        List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        MamManager mamManager = MamManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        MamManager.MamQueryArgs mamQueryArgs = MamManager.MamQueryArgs.builder()
                .setResultPageSize(50)
                .setQueryBeforeLatestMessage(false
                .setAlwaysReturnFin(true)
                .build();
        MamQueryResult mamQueryResult = mamManager.queryArchive(mamQueryArgs);
        messageList.addAll(mamQueryResult.getMessages());

        ChatManager chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        Chat chat = chatManager.chatWith(userJid);
        chat.addMessageListener((chat1, message) -> messageList.add(message));

        return messageList;
    }
}
```